# cx_oracle reading from CSV

Tags: python, oracle, csv, cx-oracle

I have a cx_oracle connection and I am looking to run a 'batch' of sorts trying to gather ids from last names from a CSV file.  Below I have my code, in which I am getting a cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated error.

It is pointing to the line

```
and spriden_change_ind is null'''.format(lname,fname)
```

However I know this is working as you will see my commented code uses the format in this way and it works just fine.  The rows_to_dict_list is a nice function I found here sometime ago to basically add the column names to the output.

Any direction would be nice! thank you

```
import csv, cx_Oracle

def rows_to_dict_list(cursor):
    columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    new_list = []
    for row in cursor:
        row_dict = dict()
        for col in columns:
            row_dict[col] = row[columns.index(col)]
        new_list.append(row_dict)
    return new_list

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('USERNAME','PASSWORD','HOSTNAME:PORTNUMBER/SERVICEID')
cur = connection.cursor()
printHeader = True
with open('nopnumber_names.csv')as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        lname = row['Last']
        fname = row['First']
        cur.execute('''select spriden_pidm as PIDM,
                     spriden_last_name as Last,
                     spriden_first_name as First,
                     spriden_mi as Middle,
                     spriden_ID as ID
                     from spriden
                     where upper(spriden_last_name) = '{0}'
                     and upper(spriden_first_name) = '{1}'
                     and spriden_change_ind is null'''.format(lname,fname)
                    )

        # THIS RECORD RUNS FINE
        # cur.execute('''select spriden_pidm as PIDM,
        #              spriden_ID as ID,
        #              spriden_last_name as Last,
        #              spriden_first_name as First
        #              from spriden
        #              where spriden_pidm = '{}'
        #              and spriden_change_ind is null'''.format(99999)
        #             )


data = rows_to_dict_list(cur)
for row in data:
     print row
cur.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that a first name or surname somewhere in your CSV file has a `'` character in it.

You really shouldn't be building SQL by concatenating strings or using string formatting.  You are at risk of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)  if you do so.  What happens if someone has put a record in your CSV file with surname `X' OR 1=1 --`?

Instead, use bind parameters to send the values of your variables to the database. Try the following:

```
        cur.execute('''select spriden_pidm as PIDM,
                     spriden_last_name as Last,
                     spriden_first_name as First,
                     spriden_mi as Middle,
                     spriden_ID as ID
                     from spriden
                     where upper(spriden_last_name) = :lname
                     and upper(spriden_first_name) = :fname
                     and spriden_change_ind is null''',
                     {"lname": lname, "fname": fname}
                    )
```

Comment: If you hadn't made this post I just discovered two people (one in fname and one in lname who have a ' in their name. So those are definitely the culprits. Now I am wondering why it ran but I got no output even though the process was completed successfully!